# Symfony2/Doctrine won't create many-to-many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to set up a many-to-many relationship in Symfony2 with Doctrine and MySQL. As far as I can tell my annotation follows the [documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html) exactly, and I have used this exact same syntax successfully before.

Does anybody see what is wrong with this?

MyVendor/MyBundle/Entity/Feed.php:

```
namespace MyVendor\MyBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use MyVendor\MyBundle\Entity\Link;
/**
 * Feed
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Feed
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Link", mappedBy="feeds")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="feeds_links")
     */
    protected $links;
    // ...
```

MyVendor/MyBundle/Entity/Link.php:

```
namespace MyVendor\MyBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use MyVendor\MyBundle\Entity\Feed;
/**
 * Link
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Link
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Feed", mappedBy="links")
     */
    protected $feeds;
    // ...
```

But Doctrine does not create the relationship, doctrine:schema:update only generates this:

```
CREATE TABLE link (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    -- ...
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE feed (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    -- ...
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mistake in one of your annotation. One of them must be 'inversedBy', like this :

```
@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Feed", inversedBy="links")
```

Or :

```
@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Link", mappedBy="feeds")
```

I would recommend, from a general perspective, to use the SF toolbar , and especialy this :[image]

Click on this icon and it will tell you what problems your entities have, and point you directly to the annotations at fault.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Aha. That does it.  I have to wait ten minutes then I will accept your answer.  Thank you.

Comment: can you please provide a link to SF toolbar?

Comment: To access it, you need to replace in your URL app.php by app_dev.php, it should appear at the bottom of your screen. Hope this helps !